# How to use sharepoint:lookupfield control in a custom aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I've searched four several hours and came up empty.
Hopefully someone can provide me with some example code.

I'm making a custom page in sharepoint, displaying/editing data about an entry in the document list named "Documents". The document's content type has a custom column of type Lookup. The Lookup is done in the list named "Case", referring the column named "Title"

I am trying to use the SharePoint:LookupField component in the following way in my .aspx file:

```
<SharePoint:LookupField ID="lookupCase" runat="server" ControlMode="New"></SharePoint:LookupField>
```

In my code behind, I have the following:

```
lookupCase.ListId = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Case"].ID;
lookupCase.FieldName = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Case"].Fields.TryGetFieldByStaticName("Title").InternalName;
```

but nothing renders.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
 Wouter

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled more around and found the solution.

I was doing two things wrong:

1) I have to pass in the Item ID and the List ID in a URL parameter, such as:

```
ID=7&List={0845CEAB-A577-4FBD-8CEE-21A6BE08ED7E}
```

I'm guessing that this is because this component looks up some data in the SPContext.

2) In the code behind, I was referring the looked-up table, whereas I have to refer the looking-up table:

```
lookupCase.ListId = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Documents"].ID;
lookupCase.FieldName = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Documents"].Fields.TryGetFieldByStaticName("CasD").InternalName;
```